# Flutter camera and microphone permission are block in browser

Tags: flutter, browser, flutter-web

Why camera and microphone permission are block when i call web by ip(e.g. 192.168.1.2) but it work if call localhost
Help me to fix this issue please thank you so much

Comment: have you asked user to allow camera and microphone?

Comment: @Diwyansh No, just ask only in localhost .

Comment: you have to ask user to allow their Camera & Microphone.